# How to pass access token from one website to another?

Tags: facebook, oauth, cross-domain

I have a website that takes care of getting a Facebook token through Graph / OAuth. At that point, the website can post to the user's Facebook wall with no problems.

Is it possible to send this token to another website so the remote website can start posting the user's Facebook wall without re-logging in the user?

Comment: Do you access the FB API from the client (Javascript) or the server (PHP, ASP, Ruby, etc.) side? Are both websites on the same server? Are they both your websites?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET and doing everything server side (FacebookSharp API: http://goo.gl/8ylA). Both websites are on the same server, but have different domain names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access tokens are granted per APP ID, not per domain

That being said, unless your access token includes the `offline_access` permission, access tokens are bound to the current session so even if you managed to "pass" it to another domain, it wouldn't work if the user was logged out (of Facebook).

So, yes it should be possible under the right circumstances.

Comment: I just changed it to offline_access and am able to perform all Facebook API calls on website1 even while being logged out of Facebook. So how do I pass the token to website2? I am sure there are many security issues with passing it as a querystring, but what should I do?

Comment: If they're on the same server then you shouldn't have to use HTTP to send/receive the token - I'm sure the .NET framework will let you do it another way (I'm not a .NET guy)